# Visualisation of star catalogues and celestial coordinates

Tags: opengl, visualization, 3d, vector, astronomy

Does anyone have a suggested methodology for visualising the data in a star catalogue such as the Bright Star Catalogue.

I'm thinking that there would be a notional sphere and a viewpoint i.e. at the center of that sphere with two vectors representing the view direction and view horizons.

I would then somehow project from the star catalog Celestial coordinates
 coordinates (as point on the sphere) onto the viewport and draw a coloured pixel based on the color temperature of that star.

Can anyone provide any hints or suggestions?

Could it be done using billboards in OpenGL ?

or maybe a list of `GL_POINTS`

Comment: you're trying to reproduce Celestia?

Comment: nope would just like to be able to implement something basic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to **project** points on a sphere onto a plane -- which is what **map projections** do.  So yes, there are lots of resources for doing just that.  If you can't find any, comment and I'll dig some out for you.

For the celestial sphere you are looking out towards the 'surface' of the sphere from inside, rather than, when you look at a map, from a notional point above the surface of the Earth looking down.  But the maths is the same.  And for the celestial sphere if you are just making nice pictures, you can stick to spherical maths, not all the ugly stuff that has to cope with an oblate spheroid with bumps like the Earth.

Comment: thanks will investigate, do you think i would get this for free by using opengl ?

Comment: Any chance of getting more information on how to get started with a similar project. Something basic and fundamental like do we use OpenGL for this? How big should the sphere be? I've googled 'map projections' and got the wiki page, but nothing useful for how to start implementing in in code. I would hugely appreciate some kickstart guidence :)

Comment: Hi i am searching a way to show position of an object in outer surface of a sphere with c# do any one have a solution